# How to improve logic of this code?

Tags: python, loops, logic

## Code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import ntpath
import subprocess

srcPaths = sys.argv[1]
actionType = sys.argv[2]

srcPaths = srcPaths.split("\t")
srcPathsCount = len(srcPaths)

lockCount = unlockCount = 0

def fileIsLocked(srcPath):

    cmd1 = subprocess.Popen(["ls", "-ldO", srcPath], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    cmd2 = subprocess.Popen(["awk", "{ print $5 }"], stdin=cmd1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    cmd1.stdout.close()

    if "uchg" in cmd2.communicate()[0]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def setLock(flagStr, srcPath):

    global lockCount, unlockCount

    subprocess.call(["chflags", flagStr, srcPath])

    if flagStr == "uchg":
        lockCount += 1
    else:
        unlockCount += 1

for srcPath in srcPaths:

    if actionType == "Lock":

        if not fileIsLocked(srcPath):
            setLock("uchg", srcPath)

    elif actionType == "Unlock":

        if fileIsLocked(srcPath):
            setLock("nouchg", srcPath)

    else:

        if fileIsLocked(srcPath):
            setLock("nouchg", srcPath)
        else:
            setLock("uchg", srcPath)

sys.stdout.write("{}/{}/{}".format(lockCount, unlockCount, srcPathsCount))
```

The code takes `srcPaths` and `actionType` as parameters. The former is a string with tab-delimited file paths, while the latter is a string that may have values of "Lock", "Unlock", and "Toggle", which is chosen by the user.

The function `fileIsLocked(srcPath)` checks if the file is locked. It does this by using `ls -ldO` and `awk` to get the file flags. If it finds `"uchg"` there, then the function returns `True`, and vice versa. The function `setLock(flagStr, srcPath)` executes the shell script command to lock/unlock the file depending on the conditions, and keeps count of files that have been locked and unlocked.

Naturally, if the user wants to Lock the files, the file paths will be checked for unlockedness, and will proceed to lock those that are unlocked. If files are to be Unlocked, vice versa. If the user wants to Toggle, then if the files are locked, they are unlocked, and vice versa.

I'm not certain that the code is as concise as it needs to be. It seems to me like the code might be shortened or functions might be joined together. But I haven't been able to modify the code and still keep it working as intended.

What do you think could be done to improve the logic of the code?

Comment: Code Review Stack Exchange might be a better place to ask this question.

Comment: Thanks, posted it there!